# How to make CTreeCtrl::Expand not change the item positions?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

We know that the TVS_HASBUTTONS style of CTreeCtrl can display "+" or "-" before items. I want to set two icons (one for closed, one for opened) instead of the default "+" and "-", so I didn't use the TVS_HASBUTTONS style. In order to implement the function of "+" and "-", I have overrided the left mouse down handler for the icon click event, and invoked CTreeCtrl::Expand inside. But I found that the Expand method will change the item positions in the CTreeCtrl, however, "+" and "-" does not. Any solutions?

```
void CMyTreeCtrl::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    UINT uFlags;
    HTREEITEM hItem = HitTest(point, &uFlags); 
    CRect Rect,IconRect;

    if (hItem != NULL)
    {
        if (GetItemRect(hItem,&Rect,TRUE))
        {
            IconRect.left = Rect.left - 16;
            IconRect.right = Rect.left;
            IconRect.top   = Rect.top;
            IconRect.bottom = Rect.bottom;

            if (IconRect.PtInRect(point))
            {
                Expand(hItem, TVE_TOGGLE);
            }
            else
            {
                //MyMessageBox_Error(_T("not icon"));
            }
        }
    }

    CTreeCtrlDrag::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479288/ctreectrl-expand-without-scrolling

Comment: Yes, that question is the same with mine, but they didn't give a solution? The CWnd::LockWindowUpdate() and CWnd::UnlockWindowUpdate() cannot stop the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

When you expand you should not call the default OnLButtonDown handler. This will change the selected item member.

Just return after the expand. Just think that after you done the expansion your click action is done. You don't want any further action...

**Just a different Approach:**

When it is just about the different symbols, than use owner draw or custom draw for the tree Control. Than you don't Need to emulate the rest of the controll Actions and you can still use 
TVS_HASBUTTONS.

Comment: Thx. Then how to forbid the scrolling when expanding?

Comment: No idea. I never knew that there is a Scrolling on an Expand... just changed my answer an added a different Approach.